# For which languages female & male voices are available in ios text to voice framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, avspeechsynthesizer

US: English

```
Female - en-US
Male - en-GB(uk)
```

India: Hindi

```
Female - hi-IN
Male - ?
```

Spain: Spanish

```
Female - es-ES
Male - ?
```

Could anyone fill the question mark?

Comment: Hindi only have one voice, and Spanish has female with es-MX

Comment: Thanks! 'es-ES' is also female only. I need for male voice.